# Get the current route of Go_router

Tags: flutter

I am trying to mock an api request. The expected code should be 401, caused by a wrong ApiKey. When running the code from bellow I get error:
`DioException [bad response]: This exception was thrown because the response has a status code of 401 and RequestOptions.validateStatus was configured to throw for this status code.`

What is the reason I get this error and how can I solve it?

```
   test('When api key is wrong', () async {
      const queryParams = <String, dynamic>{
        'q': 'Rotterdam',
      };
      dioAdapter.onGet(
        "$baseUrl",
        queryParameters: queryParams,
        (server) => server.reply(
          401,
          "Unauthorized",
          headers: {
            'accept': ['text/json'],
            'Authorization': ['ApiKey 7968af1a-f683-4fd6-aaaa-6a7a896bb6'],
          },
          delay: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        ),
      );

      // Returns a response with 201 Created success status response code.
      var response = await dio.get(
        // baseUrl+'?q=Rotterdam',
        baseUrl,
        queryParameters: queryParams,
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'accept': 'text/json',
            'Authorization': 'ApiKey 7968af1a-f683-4fd6-aaaa-6a7a896bbb6',
          },
        )
      );

      expect(response.statusCode, 401);
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to change the title to fit the question better.